# Incorrect logic with MYSQL IF clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Im afraid the logic on my MySQL IF clause is incorrect.

I've been inserting to a table to create reports for our CSR phone agents. It pulls data from a phone database and aggregates the data for each user. Everything seems to be pretty on point except for the outbound calls. A user in this case should have had 11 but it only shows credit for 1.

In the phone database, the field `legtype1` determines inbound or outbound. If it's 1 it's outbound and if it's 2 it's inbound.

Here's the script:

```
 SELECT
      extension
      , sum(Duration) AS total_talk_time_seconds
      , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) AS total_outbound
      , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0) and ANSWERED = 1) AS total_inbound
      , sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) AS total_missed
      , SUM(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 1, 1, 0)) +                   -- outbound calls
        SUM(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 2, 1, 0) AND ANSWERED = 1) +  -- inbound calls
        SUM(IF(Answered = 1, 0, 1))  AS total_calls
FROM cdrdb.session a

    group by extension;
```

Here's sample data of the phone database:

```
extension | duration | legtype1 | answered |
--------------------------------------------
7200          20           1          0
7200          20           2          1
7200          20           1          1
7200          20           2          1
7200          20           2          1
7200          20           1          1
7200          20           2          1
7200          20           1          0
7200          20           1          1
7200          20           1          0
7200          20           2          1
7200          20           1          1
7200          20           2          1
7200          20           2          1
7200          20           1          1
7200          20           2          1
7200          20           1          0
7200          20           1          1
```

That should output:

```
Extension | Total_talk_time_seconds | total_outbound | total_inbound | missed | total_calls

7200          360                         10                8            0         18
```

Note, a call only counts as missed if it's inbound and not answered

So, I'm afraid there's an issue with my logic on the outbound condition. Can someone verify that for me and help me to refine this so that I can get my data more accurate?

Comment: There are 10 outbound calls, so it looks ok

Comment: Dear, the query isn't match with result

Comment: The output is what should be there, but in my case it's not pulling those numbers that way for some reason

Comment: You said what the results of the query should be, what results are you getting?

Comment: The 'outbound' expression is okay. The 'missing' expression should include a LEGTYPE1 check, though. Your query successfully returns 10 for total_outbound in my test: http://rextester.com/SMWUY18025.